# Laravel Blade recursion not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I a trying to generate page serial with children but not working.

My code

***Parent Blade***

```
//index.blade.php
<?php $counter = 0; ?>

@if(isset($items) && count($items))
    @foreach($items as $item)
        <tr class="success">
            <td>{{ ++$counter }}</td>
        </tr>

        @php
            $rows = $item->children()->get();
        @endphp

        @if (count($rows) > 0)
            @include('rows', ['rows' => $rows, 'counter' => $counter])
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
```

***Child Blade***

```
//rows.blade.php
@foreach($rows as $row)
    @php
        $titles = $row->getSuperTitle($row);
    @endphp
    <tr>
        <td>{{ ++$counter }}</td>
    </tr>
    @php
        $childRows = $row->children()->get();
    @endphp

    @if (count($childRows) > 0)
        @include('rows', ['rows' => $childRows, 'counter' => $counter])
    @endif
@endforeach
```

The code return the below view

[image: The result I am seeing]

But I am Looking for below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass `$counter` to include. [Check it](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#including-sub-views)

Comment: Also try without passing but no luck  @include('rows', ['rows' => $childRows])

Comment: removed from both views?

Comment: I did that on that time, but put comment with 1 as example